# Вывод записей через foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Хочу вывести записи в два блока list-group (если запись с id_user == 1 то в один блок вносить, а если id_user == 3 то в другой ). Но они выводятся каждая запись отдельно. Что я делаю не так?

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [tasks] => Задача 1
    [id_user] => 3
)
    
    stdClass Object
(
    [tasks] => Задача 2
    [id_user] => 3
)
    
    stdClass Object
(
    [tasks] => Задача 3
    [id_user] => 3
)
    
    stdClass Object
(
    [tasks] => Задача 4
    [id_user] => 3
)
    
    stdClass Object
(
    [tasks] => Задача 1
    [id_user] => 1
)
    
    stdClass Object
(
    [tasks] => Задача 2
    [id_user] => 1
)
```

```html
foreach($data['getTask'] as $Tasks){ //print_r($Tasks);
    if($Tasks->id_user == 1){ ?>
        <div class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item active">M</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $Tasks->tasks ?></li>
        </div> 
    <?php }
    if($Tasks->id_user == 3){ ?>
        <div class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item active">P</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $Tasks->tasks ?></li>
        </div>  
    <?php }
}
```

Нужно вот так, что бы было все в кучке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну дак если вы группу выводите при каждой итерации, дак чего ожидаете то?

Comment: используйте два цикла

Comment: можно пример кода если не сложно. Я пытался с двумя циклами делать и не выходило.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если опустить тот факт, что а данном моем ответе написан говнокод, ибо я в принципе не приемлю вывод html непосредственно в php, то решение задачи представляется следующим.

Допустим вы взяли данные из json (ну или еще откуда то, что получили `stdClass`):

```
$json_data = '[{"tasks":"Задача 1","id_user":3},
               {"tasks":"Задача 2","id_user":3},
               {"tasks":"Задача 3","id_user":3},
               {"tasks":"Задача 4","id_user":3},
               {"tasks":"Задача 1","id_user":1},
              {"tasks":"Задача 2","id_user":1}]';
$data = json_decode($json_data);
```

Теперь вы хотите разделить задачи на группы по пользователям. Для этого сначала определите уникальные идентификаторы пользователей:

```
$uids = array_unique( array_map(function($item){ return $item->id_user; }, $data));
sort($uids);
```

*Заметьте, что если бы у вас был не массив `stdClass`, а просто вложенные массивы, то можно было бы обойтись `array_unique(array_column($data, 'id_user'))`. Если же вы все таки десериализовали данные из json, то второй булевый-парамер овтечает за преобразование объектов в массивы, а не классы, т.е. `json_decode($json_data, true)` даст двух-уровневый массив, а не массив объектов.*

ну а теперь говнокод:

```
foreach($uids as $uId){ ?>

    <div class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item active">user: <?= $uId ?></li>
    <?

    foreach($data as $d){
        if($d->id_user != $uId) continue;
        ?>
        <li class="list-group-item"><?= $d->tasks ?></li>
        <?
    }?>
    </div>
    <?
}
```

Этот код генерирует следующую разметку

```
<div class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item active">user: 1</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Задача 1</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Задача 2</li>
</div>

<div class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active">user: 3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Задача 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Задача 2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Задача 3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Задача 4</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Все равно не то (вышло так же как и было только пробел больше). Я скрины приложил выше. Так как должно быть

Comment: @Andrii да, потерял фрагмент заголовка `<li class="list-group-item active"></li>`. `li` элементы обычно заворачивают в `ul,ol`, а не в дивы, если что.

Comment: но вышло не так же как было. у вас были 6 блоков `list-group` у меня же только два.

Comment: кароче я лох, у меня выше было echo "<pre>"; и потому были пробелы, спасибо